# Generified class and inheritance issue

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a parent class `Builder` which can be generified with parameter of `Builder` type or its subtype:

```
class Builder<T extends Builder> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T doSmth() {
        System.out.println("do smth");
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

It has a subclass - `BuilderChild`:

```
class BuilderChild extends Builder<BuilderChild> {

    BuilderChild doSmthElse() {
        System.out.println("do smth else");
        return this;
    }
}
```

So, I can call method `doSmth` on `BuilderChild` instance and it returns `BuilderChild`:

```
new BuilderChild().doSmth().doSmthElse();
```

But when I tried to generify `BuilderChild` the line above stopped compile.

```
class BuilderChild<T> extends Builder<BuilderChild> {

    BuilderChild doSmthElse() {
        System.out.println("do smth else");
        return this;
    }
}
...
//Compile error, because doSmth() 
//returns Builder instead of BuilderChild.
new BuilderChild().doSmth().doSmthElse();
```

Can someone explain why `doSmth()` started return `Builder` after I generified `BuilderChild`? Are there any ways to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `BuilderChild` as a raw type.

That means that it has type arguments, but you specify it without supplying any type parameters.

This means that pretty much all generics information of that type will be ignored (it's [a bit more complicated than that](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8), but that's the high-level view).

If you write this instead:

```
new BuilderChild<Object>().doSmth().doSmthElse();
```

then it compiles.

Also, `doSmthElse` should be specified as `BuilderChild<T> doSmthElse()`.

Note that raw types are only supported for backwards compatibility and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something like:

```
abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> {

    protected T getThis();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T doSmth() {
        System.out.println("do smth");
        return getThis();
    }
}

class BuilderChild extends Builder<BuilderChild> {
    protected T getThis() { return this; }
    [...]
```

Although client code is probably better off making the builder non-generic.